# Swift Combine complex api request

Tags: swift, api, request, combine, publisher

I just started to learn Combine and therefore I can't figure out how to make a complex request to the API.

It is necessary to create an application where the user can enter the name of the company's GitHub account in the input field and get a list of open repositories and their branches.

There are two API methods:

1. https://api.github.com/orgs/<ORG_NAME>/repos This method returns a list of organization account repositories by name. For example, you can try to request a list of Apple's repositories https://api.github.com/orgs/apple/repos

struct for this method

```
struct Repository: Decodable {

 let name: String

 let language: String?

    enum Seeds {
        public static let empty = Repository(name: "", language: "")
    }

}
```

2. https://api.github.com/repos/<ORG_NAME>/<REPO_NAME>/branches This method will be needed to get the branch names in the specified repository.

struct for this method

```
struct Branch: Decodable {

 let name: String

}
```

As a result, I need to get an array of such structures.

```
struct BranchSectionModel {
    var name: Repository
    var branchs: [Branch]
}
```

For this I have two functions:

```
func loadRepositorys(orgName: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Repository], Never> {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/orgs/\(orgName)/repos" ) else {
            return Just([])
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Repository].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

and

```
func loadBranchs(orgName: String, repoName: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Branch], Never> {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/repos/\(orgName)/\(repoName)/branches") else {
            return Just([])
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Branch].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    }
```

Both of these functions work separately, but I don't know how to end up with an [BranchSectionModel] . I guess to use flatMap and sink, but don't understant how.

I do not understand how to combine these two requests in one thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're looking to convert one publisher into another, [`.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/map(_:)-99evh) and [`.switchToLatest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/switchtolatest()-453ht). In this case, since you're also looking to turn one publisher into many (and then back down into one), [`MergeMany`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/mergemany) will also be a useful tool:

```
loadRepositorys(orgName: orgName)
    .map { repos in
        Publishers.MergeMany(repos.map { repo in
            loadBranchs(orgName: orgName, repoName: repo.name)
                .map { branches in
                    BranchSectionModel(name: repo, branchs: branches)
                }
        })
        .collect(repos.count)
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink { result in
        print("---")
        print(result)
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Although I'm a big fan of Combine, I don't think it's particularly well suited to this task, compared with async/await, which will probably be a little less confusing and look cleaner. As a learning exercise, it's a great one, but if you were to tackle this problem in the real world, async/await would likely be my go-to.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Your method works, but the problem is that it returns single elements. And I would like to get an array of such elements immediately at the output.

P.S. Maybe you know where you can see examples with similar chains of requests? Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: I've added `.collect(repos.count)` to the end of the `MergeMany`, which now changes the output to a single array. Hopefully this fits what you're looking for.